# Integrate iOS Xcode Build Node with Jenkins X + Tekton

Tags: ios, jenkins-x

We are currently investigating in replacing our old QuickBuild CI setup with a modern cloud-native solution that is integrated into our k8s cluster. Jenkins X with Tekton (without classic Jenkins) sounds very promising.

We do not only have k8s applications though. Especially our iOS builds need to be executed on a Mac build node, and thus cannot run in k8s.

(How) is it possible to integrate a Mac build node into Jenkins X + Tekton?

Comment: I found this article that could be helpful: https://medium.com/@dlorenc/tekton-on-mac-ed6ea72d1efb

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OS X builds can be done with Tekton yet. For builds that need OS X, I would currently consider to use [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) with support for [macOS actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-software).

Comment: We don’t use Github, we use an on-premise git hosting solution.